# Cypress env variable getting changed

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to pass an integer value of length 19 as cypress env variable,but its getting changed as I run cypress

```
npx cypress open --env id=8802129083456781238
```

[image]

How do I get the actual value ?? (Cannot pass as string via cypress.json)

Comment: can you also mention how are you using the id value in your tests ?

Comment: Cypress.env(''id")

Comment: Please clarify "Cannot pass as string via cypress.json" - you tried and it didn't work?

Comment: Please note, the number you have is a [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt), and it's tricky to handle via the command line but easy via `cypress.json`.